# How to use 2d texture in a level

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I'm having a problem with putting a 2d texture into a level. There is always the part above the mesh (https://imgur.com/TizVf1O) and I don't know how to get rid of it

texture: https://imgur.com/8fCzfTh
material: https://imgur.com/ueJu7zJ

Thanks for any help

Comment: You have to give a little more details about your setup if you want an answer. From three screenshots, I am as clueless as you are.

Comment: What else can i provide you?

Comment: How is your mesh setup? What are the UVs, etc.? A little more sources of error. It looks to me, like your problem is the alpha itself or the UVs.